# MAC-1 assembly recursion

Tags: assembly, recursion

How would you call a recursive function in MAC-1 assembler?

In c++ you would do something like:

```
int func(int num)
{
    if(num == 0) return 1;
    return num * func(num-1);
}
```

I know how to call function using

```
CALL
```

and how to load parameters on stack and take it of, I also have multiplication instruction made by myself, so

```
MUL 6
```

would do:

```
ac = ac * 6
```

but I cant figure out how to call recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cant figure out how to call recursive

There's not much to it. You just do a call to the same function that you're in, and save everything from the current call on the stack.

For example (pseudo code):

```
n=3, CALL func
  (n==3):  PUSH n, n--, CALL func
    (n==2):  PUSH n, n--, CALL func
      (n==1):  PUSH n, n--, CALL func
        (n==0):  ac=1, RET
      POP n, ac *= n, RET 
    POP n, ac *= n, RET  
  POP n, ac *= n, RET
```

Comment: Or if the code is susceptible to tail call optimization, he can reuse the current stack frame :)