# MAC-1 assembly recursion sample

Tags: recursion

I have the similar question as described here: [MAC-1 assembly recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009680/mac-1-assembly-recursion)

But I am a total newbie for MIC-1 / MAC-1 and looking for some ideas / samples on how to start. I need to calculate a faculty via recursion in MAC-1 ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well to get used to the MIC-1 simulator, use the following link:

http://www.ontko.com/mic1/mal.html

But before that, I guess you want to understand how the MIC-1 microprocessor works. Use chapter 4 of this textbook to understand all that is involved:

Structured Computer Organization 6th edition by Andrew S. Tanenbaum